# updating mongoose model with new field

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to update all the documents in my collection with new field I declare in my model. this field is boolean with default value of false.

I know this question is already asked before but still can't get solution for my problem.

everything I try not working.

here for examples for what i tried:
update method that has empty query -cause I want to update all documents,
and empty $set because I don't want to do any change, just add the field I added in my model

```
User.update({},{},{multi: true},function(err,num) {
  if (err){
  console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(num);
  console.log("all documents were updated with new field)
  })
```

another try :

```
    User.find({},function (err,docs) {
          async.each(docs,function (doc,cb) {
              doc.save(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                cb();
              })
           },function () {
          console.log("all documents were saved with new field)
          })
       })
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You should probably explicitly add the field to the update $set (with its default value), because Mongoose doesn't know which documents in the database may or may not have that field already so it doesn't know for which documents it has to set the default (although it may be easier/faster to run the update operation from the Mongo shell)

Answer (score 2):

Mongoose does not allow to set `undefined` values to fields. Those fields are absent from the document. You need to pass something to Mongoose to set as the value of that *new field*.

So you could set an empty String -

```
User.update({},{$set: {newField: ''}}......)
```

or null -

```
User.update({},{$set: {newField: null}}.....)
```

but you need to provide some values in order for Mongoose to set it to the documents.

**Edit** -

From the mongoose documentation -

> By default, mongoose only applies defaults when you create a new document. It will not set defaults if you use update() and findOneAndUpdate(). However, mongoose 4.x lets you opt-in to this behavior using the setDefaultsOnInsert option.

You can read more about it [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html).

Comment: I know i can do it like this, but it not useful to me, 
i need to write generic script that i will run every time i add new field to my model.

Comment: and why would mongoose will try to save undefined value if it has default value in the model?

Comment: @masterG Sorry I didn't notice that you've given a default value. Please check my edited answer.